# error in flutter doctor command showing me error

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-doctor

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UhAP.png)

I don't have any other Android studio installed.

I have already `jre` folder in the Android studio.

I have Flutter install.

flutter command is also working.

flutter doctor is not working.

I have done the `flutter config --android-sdk` '/path/to/android/sdk' as well
nothing is working for me
I am using windows

Answer (score -1):

are you using the Flutter terminal or the Windows built-in terminal, if so to run flutter doctor you have to use the Flutter command prompt which you can find in Flutter folder and it should be named `flutter console`.

Comment: thats not correct, he is properly running flutter doctor, just android studio is not completely setup. 

In android studio there should be an SDK Manager window/view and there you need to make sure you have sdks installed for the android versions you want to support

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).